# Mounting network storage over wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, mount, gentoo, fstab

I have a laptop that is connected to my home network over wireless connection. The laptop runs a bit torrent client which downloads to a mounted NAS filesystem . I would like the laptop the run the bit torrent client on startup but this of course requires mounting the remote filesystem first. I tried placing an entry in `/etc/fstab` but this obviously fails because when mount occurs the laptop is not yet associated with the wireless network.

I would like to know what is the best practice in this situation. I would also like to support situations in which the specific wireless network is not available - in that case the client should not be started at startup.

One last thing - my distribution is Gentoo so a solution that takes advantage of `/etc/cond.d/net` configuration options is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies in init scripts can be configured with the depend directive, as specified in this documentation page:

http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=4

When an init script has a dependency, it doesn't run until that dependency is satisfied.